# pandas dataframe style format not printing specified precision

Tags: python, pandas, format

I am trying to format the dataframe using https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html.

But, I am not getting the desired result:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 1.534231, 'A'], [2.32453251, np.nan, 3.0]])
>>> df.style.format(na_rep='MISS', precision=3)
<pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x7f0b32eff740>
>>> print(df.head())
          0         1    2
0       NaN  1.534231    A
1  2.324533       NaN  3.0

>>> print(pd.__version__)
1.5.3
```

with

```
python --version
Python 3.12.0rc3
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Styler.format` is used to apply as specific formatting to a `pandas DataFrame`. So the data present in the dataframe doesn't change but when you display it in a specific environment, the styling will be applied to the data.
So when you write the following code,

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 1.534231, 'A'], [2.32453251, np.nan, 3.0]])
>>> df.style.format(na_rep='MISS', precision=3)
<pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x7f0b32eff740>
```

Notice the last line, where a `Styler` object is returned.

You can hold this `Styler` object in another variable as follows.

Now, to display this formatted `df`, let's make the environment into a `HTML` web browser environment.

As both `Styler` and `pandas.DataFrame` have a `to_html()` method, lets convert the `df` into `html code` and view into in the web browser.

```
>>> import webbrowser
>>> with open('str.html', 'w') as f:
        s=df.style.format(na_rep='MISS', precision=3)
        s.to_html(f)
>>> webbrowser.open_new_tab('str.html') 
True
```

The above code pops up a new tab with the page `'str.html'` stored locally, where you can easily view the formatted `df`.

Answer (score 1):

The `style.format()` function does not alter your data(frame) but rather displays it in the desired formatting.

If I run your code (in a Jupyter notebook) I get this output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 1.534231, 'A'], [2.32453251, np.nan, 3.0]])
df.style.format(na_rep='MISS', precision=3)

# alternatively add an explicit display function
# note that print() does not work here
# display(df.style.format(na_rep='MISS', precision=3))

    0   1   2
0   MISS    1.534   A
1   2.325   MISS    3.000
```

This makes sense, since you probably don't want to change your data but rather only format it in a specific context for display purposes.